# nmcli - save wifi connection

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I used command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager (`nmcli`) to "Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot", like following:

```
# nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid X password X ifname wlan1
Device 'wlan1' successfully activated with 'a8168e88-e391-45b9-95e3-5b66fb10fd31'.
#
```

Is there a way preserve this state somehow? Otherwise after restart I have to re-run same command again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add connection not to change device properties. Something like this:

```
nmcli connection add con-name WiFi type wifi ifname wlan1 ipv4.method auto autoconnect yes wifi.ssid X wifi-sec.psk Y.
```

I don't have WiFi interface on machine I'm currently using so I cannot test it. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: you are missing the wireless-security property. Like WPA-PSK.    
the property can be defined via 'wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk'    

Full command:    
```
nmcli connection add con-name WiFi type wifi ifname wlan1 ipv4.method auto autoconnect yes wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi.ssid ssid-name wifi-sec.psk wifipassword

```